# Image drag and drop in wpf application

Tags: wpf, image, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop an image on wpf application form. Can anyone provide me the code and other links for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to D&D within a single WPF application; then this code should get you going:

[Drag and Drop within WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/942d19a8-b862-48aa-883a-d59ad6acaa2a)

If you want to D&D between WPF applications, or between another non-WPF application you've got some options, but probably the easiest is to use a bitmap transfer (it takes a bit more code, so let me know and I'll publish it).

Comment: I'd like to know how to do it from a non-WPF application into a WPF app. I'm working with images.