# DragDrop a non-text object to RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

I am trying to drag and drop non text object from Label to RichTextBox. But when I move mouse over the RTB it doesn't allow me to drop.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            richTextBox1.Drop+=new DragEventHandler(richTextBox1_Drop);
            richTextBox1.DragEnter +=new DragEventHandler(richTextBox1_DragEnter);
            richTextBox1.DragOver+=new DragEventHandler(richTextBox1_DragOver);  

            labelSender.MouseDown+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(labelSender_MouseDown);
        }

        private void richTextBox1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            DropContent dropContent = (DropContent)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DropContent));
            richTextBox1.AppendText(dropContent.Content);
        }

        private void richTextBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        private void richTextBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        private void labelSender_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop((Label)sender, new DropContent("HelloRichTextBox"), DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    public class DropContent //Object containing dragging data
    {
        public string Content;
        public DropContent(string content)
        {
            this.Content = content;
        }
    }
```

It seems like RTB allows to drop only Text.

Comment: Your DropContent class seems only interested in text.  Any object can be dragged, what you do with it in the drop event handler is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The code part from "Xcalibur37" which solve this exact problem is in the dragOver event:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Hope it solve other people problems, because it solved mine and it was exactly the initial question.

You can view his full answer on this page: [Drag and drop a path in a wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455977/drag-and-drop-a-path-in-a-wpf/8457362#8457362)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your drag/drop methods and DropContent class. You just have to write MouseDown method:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true;  
        labelSender.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(labelSender_MouseDown)
    }

    private void labelSender_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop((Label)sender, ((Label)sender).Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```