# How to get drop Location/Path during DragDrop opetaion in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

How to get Drop Location/Path while Dragging items to desktop using DoDragDrop in WPF?

As an example if I drag an item from WPF window and drop to Desktop how can I get the address of the Desktop as **"C:\Users\somnath\Desktop"**.

Is there any property any event which provides me the drop location?

```
string[] paths = ...;
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, paths),
                    DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455977/drag-and-drop-a-path-in-a-wpf

Comment: @RachelGallen No its not! Please read my question carefully once.